# Stack Overflow Careers RSS Developer's Terms of Use

Tags: support, jobs, feed, legal, terms-of-service

A couple months ago I looked for a Stack Overflow Careers Android app. I found [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benlakey.stackcareers) but ultimately found it to be lacking features and abandoned, so I created my own app from scratch to fill the void:

[CareerStack [Unofficial]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ovrhere.android.careerstack) - It uses the RSS feed to search Stack Overflow Careers' job listings while providing multiple themes (Dark + Light) and tablet support.

Currently the user base is small but now I am wondering a couple issues:

1. **Is one allowed to create an *unofficial* app to search the Stack Careers listings?**

Provided said app is free, labelled "Unofficial", indicates the source is Stack Overflow, and that jobs link back to the original site. I suspect this to be ok, based on pre-existing app and what I've read in the coverall [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service).

2. **Provided the first is allowed, can one have *OPTIONAL* advertising on the app?**

This may be more questionable, even if there is a checkbox to disable it. However, it could be considered somewhat similar to a donate button (if the donations were $0.0001).

I am aware I should have clarified this before release but what's done is done and I wish some clarity going forward.

---

**Edit:** I've decided to forgo ads in said app. However, I am leaving it as part of the question for general knowledge. Also, formatting and extra information.

Comment: The [tag:android-app] is reserved to Stack Exchange official app.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oops, sorry. The tag was suggested to me, I should have checked it more carefully.